# The word "tagging" meaning in the context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of tagging in this context below?

> This was the Glendale photographer’s third year of organizing a breastfeeding mothers’ photo, but something about the timing this year led to an overwhelming response. “I had moms from all over Arizona **tagging** other moms, saying, ‘Please do this,’ ‘Please do this,’ ‘You have to go do this,’ ” Atkins tells Yahoo Beauty.

<sup>Source: [Yahoo Beauty](https://www.yahoo.com/beauty/powerful-group-breastfeeding-photo-declares-right-192220704.html)</sup>

I searched the word Tag in the dictionary. It seems to me none of them can fit for this context. Can someone help to advise which one is fit?

1. To label, identify, or recognize with a tag or other identifier: I tagged him as a loser.
2. To put a ticket on (a motor vehicle) for a traffic or parking violation.
3. To add as an appendage to: tagged an extra paragraph on the letter.
4. To follow closely: Excited children tagged the circus parade to the end of its route.
5. To cut the tags from (sheep).
6. To add a taggant to: explosives that were tagged with coded microscopic bits of plastic.
7. Slang To mark or vandalize (a surface) with a graffiti tag: tagged the subway walls.

Comment: The earlier bit of context is helpful here "...Atkins wrote on Facebook, where she posted the photo on Sunday night. " [Tagging is an action you can take on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/124970597582337/) and the word has a special meaning there. That is why it is so important to include where you found the text you're asking about.

Comment: @ColleenV: Oh, thanks for that information! Most of US websites including Facebook & Tweeter had been blocked in my area, so I can not use them. I will try to find the link again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On social media, "tagging someone" is when you @ their user name or name and it gives them a notification where they can click to see the post. This is what happens often on Facebook public posts and photos.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward to me. Moms were contacting other moms on social networks to join the event, hence, using internet slang, former moms were "tagging" other moms

Comment: So 'tagging' means 'contacting'？

Comment: No, tagging is a word commonly used in technology to describe the act of adding metadata to some content. For example a smartphone that takes a photo can embed info to that photo like the location where the photo has been taken (geotag)

Comment: This Wiki post might help: [How to tag someone on Facebook](http://www.wikihow.com/Tag-People-on-Facebook).